# On click, making a menu disappear on menu. The "show" works, but the "hide" doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, click

I have a portfolios item inside my menu, which then becomes a dropdown menu on hover for desktop and click for mobile. The problem with mobile is that the first click shows the menu, which is all good, but the next clicks don't change anything.

I've tried `.toggle()`, `.toggleClass()`, both of which don't seem to work. I'm currently testing out an if/else statement, shown in the JavaScript below. "If the window width is less than 940px"... and then "if the current `visibility` is `hidden`, change it to `visibility: visible` on click of the parent" and vice versa for the else.

**Edit:**

I'm only testing this in browser windows that are less than 940px to emulate the "mobile" experience.

**Edit #2:**

I removed the `if window width < 940px` for the purposes of this question since it might be easier to respond to that way?

```js
$(function() {
  
  if ($('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'hidden') == true) {
    $('.nav__portfolio').on('click', function() {
      $('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

  } else {
    $('.nav__portfolio').on('click', function() {
      $('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
  }
  
};
```

```css
.nav__portfolio ul {
  visibility: hidden;
```

```html
<li class="nav__portfolio"><p>PORTFOLIO</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: How does your html markup look like?

Comment: You really should be doing this in one `click` event handler

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that. New to this, am going to edit the question now.

Comment: You don't have an else for your first check for window width so your code, if it works, will only work if the window is <= 940 px wide. Definitely post your html too, as @empiric said.

Comment: I'm currently testing this code only in browser windows that are less than 940px. I'm using the Chrome dev tools function that emulates the mobile experience, the device toolbar I believe? Sorry should've made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main problem is the condition you pass to the if statement:

- `$('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'hidden')` isn't a boolean so it doesn't return `true` or `false`

What you can do is compare the actual value for that css property like this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($('div').css('visibility') !== 'hidden') {
    $('div').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('div').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle the div</button>
<div></div>
```

---

This logic on your actual code will be something like:

```
$('.nav__portfolio').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
    $('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    $('.nav__portfolio ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using this method but unfortunately, it wouldn't work. I understand the logic but I suppose something or another just doesn't add up :( .

Comment: Well glad to help u understand the logic of your actual code @wyang but if it isn't working you will need to replicate your issue on codepen or jsfiddle and let us see the entire code

Answer (score 0):

With the `toggle()` method:

```js
$('.nav__portfolio').on('click', function() {
   $('.nav__portfolio ul').toggle();
})
```

```css
.nav__portfolio ul {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav__portfolio"><p>PORTFOLIO</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
    <li>Dropdown Item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! This method for the most part works. However, on the very first click, the <ul> doesn't show; it only shows on the second click. Everything after that works fine. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I changed the css attribute to `display: none`. Tell me if it works now.

Comment: Unfortunatey not :( . With display: none, the second click doesn't even work anymore, the dropdown no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hasClass/addClass/removeClass instead?

probably only need one click listener

```
if ($(window).width() <= 940) {

    $('.nav__portfolio').on('click', function() {
        if ($('.nav__portfolio ul').hasClass('visibleClass') {
            $('.nav__portfolio ul').removeClass('visibleClass');
        } else {
            $('.nav__portfolio ul').addClass('visibleClass');
        }
    });
}

.nav__portfolio ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav__portfolio ul.visibleClass {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this was the first method I tried. I usually use this method but somehow it's just not working in my case today. Thank you though!

Comment: can you post a fiddle?